# Change data model to use google cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-maker

I have developed an application using google app maker, the data model is using google drive tables. Is it possible to use the same application but change the data sources to use google cloud SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can export the data to a Google spreadsheet, create a new datasource for Cloud SQL, and import that data with the same spreadsheet into Cloud SQL through Appmaker. 
(Or, if you wanted, put that data in a CSV and manipulate it from your MySQL client)

**Note:** You will have to recreate your data relations.

[Export as described here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export#export_data_to_a_google_spreadsheet)

Importing data from sheets into Cloud SQL has worked smoothly for me in the past.